# How to call an another js class

Tags: javascript, extjs

I try to call a constructed object in another class in order to build a histogram , but Its not working

this is my first class where I have my object :

```
enter code here**
 * @class Ext.app.PortalHistogram
 * @extends Object
 */

 Ext.define('Ext.app.PortalHistogram', {

    extend: 'Ext.chart.Chart',  

    // --------------------------------------
    // Properties 
    // --------------------------------------
    xtype: 'chart', 
    alias: 'widget.PortalHistogram',
    histoHeight: 75,    
    histoWidth: 300,
    histoBarPadding:2,
    histoMode: 'pourcent',  
    histoBarHeight: 60,
    histoBarWidth : 10,
    storeUrl : 'http://localhost/getDataJson.php',
    animate: true,
    shadow: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

    // --------------------------------------
    // Constructor
    // --------------------------------------
        initComponent: function(){

      this.setHeight(this.histoHeight);
      this.setWidth(this.histoWidth);           

        // store creation
     var itemStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
      model: 'PortalHisto',
      fields: ['NumBar', 'Timestamp', 'dataValue', 'overrideBarColor'],
                    proxy: { type: 'ajax', url : storeUrl, reader: {type:json'}}
  });

        store: itemStore;           
        axes: [{
            type: 'Numeric',
            position: 'left',
            fields: ['dataValue'],
            minimum: 0,
            maximum: 100
        }, {
            type: 'Category',
            position: 'bottom',
            fields: ['NumBar'],
            title: 'NumBar',
            label: {
                rotate: {
                    degrees: 90
                }
            }
        }];

        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            axis: 'left',
            gutter: 80,
            xField: 'NumBar',
            yField: ['dataValue'],               
            style: {
                fill: '#38B8BF'
            }
        }];
    }
```

I try to call it on my new class : 
ddfdfd

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />   
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ext-all.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ext-all.js"></script>        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/PortalHistogram.js"></script>        

        <script type="text/javascript">
            Ext.require(['Ext.app.PortalHistogram']);
            Ext.onReady(function(){         

                var mychart = Ext.create('Ext.app.PortalHistogram', {
                    histoHeight: 300, 
                    histoWidth: 500,
                });                     

                Ext.create('widget.panel', {
                    width: 800,
                    height: 400,
                    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                    items: mychart
                });
            });         
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span id="app-msg" style="display:none;"></span>
        <div id="Div_histo001"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I dont have any displaying and i dont know what is my error
my goal is to built a bar chart with extjs by creating an object and call it in other class

Comment: Are there any errors in the debug console?

Comment: with the changes, I have these errors : 

Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation extensions::SafeBuiltins:82

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined ext-all.js:21

Answer (score 0):

Change the xtype of `Ext.app.PortalHistogram` to `mychart` or whatever and try:

```
Ext.create('widget.panel', {
    width: 800,
    height: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'mychart',
        histoHeight: 300,
        histoWidth: 500
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks I have changed it, but it still not work.

I have these errors :

Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation extensions::SafeBuiltins:82

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined ext-all.js:21